# JavaScript: 2 window.opener.location.href statements with alert() in between not functioning

Tags: javascript, window, window.opener

I need to make a little JS app to scroll automatically through a list of URLs.  I've chosen to have the functionality in a pop-up, for various reasons.

The syntax to change the opening window's URL is:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

This works fine with one URL, but if two statements are called, only one is executed.  I experimented with an alert statement between two of the above statements, and the alert event made the second statement function properly:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://www.example1.com";
alert("hello world");
window.opener.location.href = "http://www.example2.com";
```

Question is: does anyone know how to get the first and second window.opener statements to work, without the intervening alert();?  Also, how can I add a pause between the two statements, so that the second executes a couple of seconds after the first?

Thanks so much!

Comment: see if that title works any better (if not change it back :). Hard to describe concisely.

Comment: *"This works fine with one URL, but if two statements are called, only one is executed"* Which one? I suspect they're *both* executed, it's just that you only see the result from one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `setTimeout`, like this:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://www.example1.com";

setTimeout(function() {
    window.opener.location.href = "http://www.example1.com";
}, 5000);        //5,000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the original location of the opener page also at `http://www.example1.com`?  If not, then when the first statement executes and it changes the location of the opener to a different domain, then the `window.opener` property becomes not accessible -- hence the second statement fails.